# How to send large file using sockets?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

i have a zip file (15 mb), want to send this to android socket connection, i can able to emit via the following code :

```
fs.readFile('path',function(err,fileData){
io.to(socketId).emit('sendFile',{'file':fileData.toString('base64')});
});
```

using the above code, low size file is emitting without any delay, if there is any large size file emitting is delayed. how to achieve this in a better way.

Comment: There are practical limits to how large a single message you can send with socket.io/webSockets just like with TCP.  I'd suggest you look at the Google search results for "streaming over socket.io" or "streaming over webSocket" and pick one of those solutions.  You will ultimately want to send your file in chunks and have those chunks reassembled at the other end and probably use a system that does not require the entire large file to be held in memory at both ends.

Answer (score 10):

You can try to use [socket.io-stream](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream) like in the below example:

server:

```
'use strict';
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
const ss = require('socket.io-stream');
const fs = require('fs');

var filename = 'test.zip';   // 80MB file

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('client connected');
  socket.on('sendmeafile', function () {
    var stream = ss.createStream();
    stream.on('end', function () {
        console.log('file sent');
    });
    ss(socket).emit('sending', stream); 
    fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(stream);
  });  
});

console.log('Plain socket.io server started at port 3000');
```

client:

```
'use strict';
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000');
const ss = require('socket.io-stream');
const fs = require('fs');

var filename = 'test-copy.zip';

socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('connected');
  socket.emit('sendmeafile');
});

ss(socket).on('sending', function(stream) {
  stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)); 
  stream.on('end', function () {
    console.log('file received');
  });
});
```

As jfriend00 wrote in his comment you don't need http.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in the above example you are receiving the file on streaming, but in my case file is already in the server, so what i am doing here is fs.readFile from the server and emiting to the destination like :  fs.readFile('path',function(err,fileData){
io.to(socketId).emit('sendFile',{'file':fileData.toString('base64')});
}); .... how can i implement the io-stream here?

Comment: In my example the file is on the server too and the server sends the stream to the client. The client is also a node app. Do you want to send a file to a browser?

Comment: here my client is android, there is any possibilities?

Comment: But... let me understand.. do you have an android client ? Could you please show the client's code?

Comment: How can I pass the  File name or extra data from the server to to client via the  pipe

Comment: Suppose I am sending a file like client1->server->client2, If I pass the stream from client1->server->client2 and do createWriteStream there will it work?